# XMLHttpRequest error: Origin not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to create an AddOn for Firefox which will fetch only RSS feeds from particular website. But I am getting an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.-** Origin
>   `http://localhost:59382` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Can anyone explain how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Same-origin policy applies to web content, but cross-domain requests are possible in FF add-ons. See **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extension_Frequently_Asked_Questions#I_cannot_initiate_an_XMLHttpRequest_from_my_extension)** and **[here](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest)** for two ways of accomplishing this.

p.s.: If you are interested, there are some nifty ways to do cross-site requests in plain old sites, **[using YQL (yahoo query language)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206753/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery-using-yql)** (and **[here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)**) and even **[CSSHttpRequest](https://github.com/nbio/csshttprequest)** (I haven't tried the latter, but I've seen some cool demos).

Answer (score 0):

it's the classic [cross-origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) problem. You migth want to read [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) too.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the normal xhr from one domain to another.
You need to use the new XHR or the one speciall made for addons.
If you're on GM, it's the one starting with GM_*