# Combine 2 urls into 1

Tags: url, hyperlink

I would like to combine 2 urls into 1 clickable link. The first link is a link that sets a cookie and the second is a query.

1st link: http://www.homeaway.com/?CID=a_cj_7123410&utm_source=cj&utm_medium=affiliates&utm_content=7123410&utm_campaign=10938928

2nd: http://www.homeaway.com/search/keywords:boston

Thanks

Marc

Comment: Not sure you can do that as standard link. Can have first page redirect to the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'combine' the two URLs, but you can make a request to both of them using Javascript.

Unfortunately, because the URL is on another domain you can't simply make an AJAX request. However you can use a web service like Yahoo's YQL to do this for you.

This approach is explained here: (see accepted answer). 
[Cross-domain requests with JQuery using YQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206753/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery-using-yql?rq=1)

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.homeaway.com/search/keywords:boston" class="my_link">Linky</a>
```

Javascript:

```
// User clicks your link:
$('.my_link').click(function(){

    // The link to fire silently before redirecting:
    var first_url = "http://www.homeaway.com/?CID=a_cj_7123410&utm_source=cj&utm_medium=affiliates&utm_content=7123410&utm_campaign=10938928";

    // YQL query:
    var yql_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
        "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
        encodeURIComponent(first_url)+
        "%22&format=xml'&callback=?";

    // Fetch YQL URL before returning true:
    return $.getJSON(yqlUrl2Use, function(data){
        return true; // Goto the homeaway.com address.
    });
});
```